# ASP.NET Active Directory Search

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, windows-authentication, asp.net-4.5

I'm trying to create an intranet Website on ASP.NET MVC 4 using Windows Login. I have successfully done the windows login. The only thing I am stuck up with is searching the active directory with partial username. I tried searching the web and stackoverflow website but still couldn't find the answer.

```
   DirectoryEntry directory = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=NUAXIS");
   string filter = "(&(cn=jinal*))";
   string[] strCats = { "cn" };
   List<string> items = new List<string>();
   DirectorySearcher dirComp = new DirectorySearcher(directory, filter, strCats,     SearchScope.Subtree);
   SearchResultCollection results = dirComp.FindAll();
```

Comment: Can you us the code you have used to do a search on a partial username?

Comment: @rene I have added the code to the post

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
   // and with the first name (GivenName) of "Jinal*" 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.GivenName = "Jinal*";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   using (PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
   { 
      // find all matches
      foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
      {
         // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - 
         // it could be user, group, computer.....          
      }
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is on the right track.
I think you had your wildcard backwards.

Consider this:

```
search.Filter = string.Format("(&(sn={0}*)(givenName={1}*)(objectSid=*))", lastName, firstName);
```